# The degree of a constant polynomial on a finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, polynomials, finite-groups

A function $f:X\to X$ on a group $X$ is called a *polynomial* if there exists $n\in\mathbb N=\{1,2,\dots\}$ and elements $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n\in X$ such that $f(x)=a_0xa_1x\cdots xa_n$ for all $x\in X$. The smallest number $n\in\mathbb N$ in such a representation is called the *degree* of the polynomial $X$.

The constant function $1_X:X\to\{1\}\subseteq X$ on a finite group $X$ is a polynomial of degree $\le\exp(X):=\min\{n\in\mathbb N:\forall x\in X\;\;(x^n=1)\}$ because $f(x)=1=x^{\exp(X)}$ for any $x\in X$.

Each polynomial $f$ on a commutative group $X$ is of form $f(x)=ax^n$ for some $a\in X$ and $n\le\exp(X)$, which implies that $\deg(1_X)=\exp(X)$ for any finite commutative group $X$.

> **Problem 1.** Given a non-commutative finite group $X$, calculate (or evaluate) the degree $\deg(1_X)$ of the constant polynomial $1_X:X\to\{1\}\subseteq X$.

**Remark 1.** Calculations in GAP show that for any non-commutative group $X$ of order $|X|<20$, except for $A_4$ and $C_3\times S_3$, the degree of the constant function $1_X$ is equal $4$. For the groups $A_4$ and $C_3\times S_3$ this degree equals $6$.

**Remark 2.** It can be shown that $\deg(1_X)=4$ for any dihedral group $X=D_{2n}$ (because for any non-central element $b$ of order $2$ in $D_{2n}$ we have $bxxbxx=1$ for all $x\in D_{2n}$).

**Remark 3.** It is easy to see that $\deg(1_X)\ge \exp(Z(X))$, where $Z(X)=\{z\in X:\forall x\in X\;\;(xz=zx)\}$ is the center of $X$.

Keith Kearnes in his comment observed that $\deg(1_X)\ge\deg(1_{X/N})\ge\exp(Z(X/N))$ for any normal subgroup $N$ of $X$. In particular, $\deg(1_X)\ge \exp(X/[X,X])$.

> **Problem 2.** What can be said about the degree of the constant polynomial $1_X$ on a finite simple group $X$. Is $\deg(1_X)=\exp(X)$? Is this equality true for the simple group $X=A_5$?

**Remark 4.** It seems that this problem has been considered by various authors in the contexts of strong laws on groups. In particular, by Corollary 1 in [this paper of Schneider and Thom](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.11956.pdf), for the symmetric group $X=S_n$ we have $\deg(1_X)\ge \frac{n}4$, which implies that the alternating group $X=A_n$ has $\deg(1_X)\ge\frac{n}8$.

Comment: Why do you not allow polynomials of degree zero? Zero seems like the natural answer to your question.

Comment: @KeithKearnes Because allowing the degree of a constant map to be zero yields zero information about constant maps and also about the group. In contrast, the current definition (wich only positive degrees) generates many interesting and non-trivial questions.

Comment: I would find the following approach clearer: polynomials are defined as syntactic objects; degree is defined for every polynomial as the number of occurrences of variables; one defines how to interpret these syntactic objects as concrete functions. Finally, the question posted here would be about when two polynomials interpret as the same function. (E.g., when a polynomial of positive degree interprets as a constant function.)

Comment: @KeithKearnes You are right, of course: polynomials are syntactic objects and their degree is the number of occurences of the variable. In majority situations this is the best definition. Algebraists instead of the degree of a function, represented by a polynomial, say about laws. But those are just reformulations of the question, which is interesting in any reformulation. The current one seems to be the shortest (and a bit surprising because it is expected that constant polynomials should have degree zero).

Comment: Remark 5: $\deg(1_G)\geq \deg(1_{G/N})$. Hence $\textrm{exp}(G)\geq \deg(1_G)\geq \textrm{exp}([G/[G,G])$.

Comment: With respect to remark 1, there's another exception at $|X| = 20$, with GAP ID (20, 3) aka GA(1,5) or Sz(2) having degree of the constant function = 8. It's also worth noting that the degree of the constant function is not, in general, the periodicity of the syntactic degrees which give rise to the same function. E.g. many small groups have degree period 2.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you for this comment because my computer calculates the degree of the constant function of the group (20,3) already the third day and I do not know when it will end up. The same situation with the group (21,1). It calculates it the third day and at the moment has stuck at polynomials of degree 5. Maybe you know what is the degree of the constant function of the group (21,1), which is a semidirect product of $C_7$ and $C_3$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Concerning the periodicity I realize that this is a rather subtle issue, but for the quaternion group $Q_8$ (which appears in a characterization of groups $X$ with $|\mathrm{Poly}(X)|=|X|\cdot\exp(X)$) it is indeed periodic (with period 4).

Comment: (21, 1): the constant function has degrees 0, 9, 12, 15, 18, ... For what it's worth, I'm not actually doing the calculations with GAP. I'm using GAP from Sage then building Cayley tables using ints as aliases, and things go much much faster that way.

Answer (score 12):

If $X = A_5$ then $\exp(X) = \mathop{\rm lcm}(2,3,5) = 30$ but
$\deg 1_X \leq 10$.  Indeed if $c \in X$ is a 5-cycle then
$$
f(x) := x c x c^2 x c^3 x c^4 x
$$
satisfies $f(x)^2 = 1$ for all $x \in X$
(in fact $f(x)$ is a double transposition unless
$x$ is in the subgroup generated by $c$ in which case of course $f(x)=1$).

*added later:*

To answer questions in the comments:
I don't have a structural explanation why $f$ works,
and a similar construction barely fails in $S_5$ (see below)
and doesn't seem to work at all in $A_6$, $A_7$ and beyond.

This $f$ was found computationally by constructing
the $A_5$ multiplication table and searching for "polynomials"
whose image misses some exponents.  Here's what the same technique
finds for some other small groups:

---

$X = S_4$ (exponent $12$): $\deg 1_X = 6$, attained for example by
$(x c x c^2 x)^2$ where $c$ is a 3-cycle.  If I computed correctly,
all degree-6 polynomials that represent $1_{S_4}$ are squares.

---

$X = S_5$ (exponent $60$): $\deg 1_X \leq 20$.  This follows from
$\deg 1_{A_5} \leq 10$ and the inequality
$$
\deg 1_X \leq \deg 1_N \cdot \deg 1_{X/N}
$$
for any normal subgroup $N$ of $X$.  To prove this inequality,
let $g$ be a polynomial on $X/N$ that represents the identity,
and lift it arbitrarily to a polynomial $\tilde g$ on $X$.
Then $\tilde g$ maps $X$ to $N$, so $\phi \circ \tilde g = 1_X$
for any polynomial $\phi$ on $N$ that represents $1_N$,
and $\deg(\phi \circ \tilde g) = (\deg \phi) (\deg \tilde g)
 = (\deg \phi) (\deg g)$.

Taking $N = A_5$ this yields the degree-20 polynomial $f(x^2)^2$ where
$f(x) = x c x c^2 x c^3 x c^4 x$ as before.  In the comments
**Taras Banakh** asked whether $f^2$ itself would work; curiously
it *almost* does: for an odd permutation $x$, the exponent of $f(x)$
is still $2$ $-$ except when $x$ is one of the 10 $4$-cycles
in the normalizer of $\langle c \rangle$, when $f(x)$ has exponent $4$.
This does mean that $f(x)^4$ is another degree-$20$ representation of $1_{S_5}$.

---

$X = {\rm GL}_3({\bf Z}/2{\bf Z})$ (the second-smallest noncyclic simple group,
which has order $168$ and exponent $84)$: $\deg 1_X \leq 36$,
attained by $(xbxcx)^{12}$ where $b$ and $c$ have order $2$ and $bc$ has order $4$.
(It turns out that for such $b,c$ no value of $xbxcx$ has exponent $7$,
though each of the remaining exponents $1,2,3,4$ does occur.)

---

Probably the upper bounds for $S_5$ and ${\rm GL_3}({\bf Z}/2{\bf Z})$
are not optimal; I wouldn't even be too surprised if $\deg 1_{A_5}$
is smaller than $10$.

Comment: Is there a slick way to see the fact that you mention about $f(x)$, or is it just a computation?

Comment: For now, just a computation.  I tried all $f$ of the form
$x a_1 x a_2 x a_3 x a_4 x$ up to conjugation, 
and the only ones that satisfied $f(x)^2 = 1$ for all $x \in A_5$
were those with $\vec a = (c,c^2,c^3,c^4)$ for some 5-cycle $c$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Is your polynomial $f$ constant also on the group $S_5$?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies What about the polynomial $f(x)=xcxc^2xc^3x\dots xc^{n-1}x$ for $n>5$, where $c$ is an $n$-cycle. Is $f(x)^2=1$ for all $x\in A_n$? or better $x\in S_n$?